# Python muiltithreading is mixing the data of different request in django

Tags: python, django, multithreading, asynchronous, django-celery

I am using python muiltithreading for achieving a task which is like 2 to 3  mins long ,i have made one api endpoint in django project.

Here is my code--

```
from threading import Thread

def myendpoint(request):
   print("hello")
   lis = [ *args ]
   obj = Model.objects.get(name =" jax")
   T1 = MyThreadClass(lis, obj)
   T1.start()
   T1.deamon = True
   return HttpResponse("successful", status=200)


Class MyThreadClass(Thread):
     def __init__(self,lis,obj):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.lis = lis
        self.obj = obj
     def run(self):
         for i in lis:
             res =Func1(i)
             self.obj.someattribute = res
             self.obj.save()


def Func1(i):
    '''Some big codes'''
    context =func2(*args)
    return context


def func2(*args):
      "' some codes "'
     return res
```

By this muiltithreading i can achieve the quick response from the django server on calling the endpoint function as the big task is thrown in another tread and execution of the endpoint thread is terminated on its return statement without keeping track of the spawned thread.

This part works for me correctly if i hit the url once , but if i hit the url 2 times as soon as 1st execution starts then on 2nd request i can see my request on console. But i cant get any response from it.

And if i hit the same url from 2 different client at the same time , both the individual datas are getting mixed up and i see few records of one client's request on other client data.

I am testing it to my local django runserver.

So guys please help , and i know about celery so dont recommend celery. Just tell me why this thing is happening or can it be fixed . As my task is not that long to use celery. I want to achieve it by muiltithreading.

Comment: At first you will have to fix the capitalization of your code.

Comment: Yeah i know , i just typed it in my mobile , but i think i made my point with whole picture. Please ignore syntax

Comment: Ok sir its done now :)